# How to use multiclient Server using boost::thread_group?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I wanna make multi client Server using boost::asio and boost::thread_group.

I tried this

```
//Listener.h 
#pragma once
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <boost/asio/io_context.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include "Session.h"
#define PORT_NUMBER 12880

class Listener
{
public:
    Listener(boost::asio::io_context& iosvc, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint& ep);

    void Start_accept();


private:
    boost::asio::io_context &_iosvc;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor _acceptor;
    boost::thread_group threadPool;
    void OnAcceptComplete(const boost::system::error_code& error, Session* session);
};
```

and this is Listener.cpp file

```
//Listener.cpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "Listener.h"
#include "SessionManager.h"

Listener::Listener(boost::asio::io_context& iosvc, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint& ep) :
    _acceptor(iosvc, ep), _iosvc(iosvc) {}


void Listener::Start_accept()
{
    //Create Client Session
    Session* new_session = clientsession::SessionManager::GetInstance()->GenerateSession(_iosvc);
    std::cout << "Listener thread ID : " << std::this_thread::get_id << '\n';
    std::cout << "Listening....." << "\n\n";
    _acceptor.async_accept(*(new_session->Socket()),
        boost::bind(&Listener::OnAcceptComplete, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, new_session));
}
void Listener::OnAcceptComplete(const boost::system::error_code& error, Session* session)
{
    if (!error) 
    {
        std::cout << "accept completed" << '\n';

        threadPool.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_context::run, &(session->_iocontext)));
        session->_iocontext.post(boost::bind(&Session::StartSession,this)); // error '->*': Cannot convert from'T*' to'Session *'.
        
        threadPool.join_all();
    }

    else
    {
        std::cout << error.message() << '\n';
    }
    Start_accept();
}
```

but session->_iocontext.post(boost::bind(&Session::StartSession,this));
// error '->*': Cannot convert from'T*' to'Session *'.

The main statement of Server is as follows.

```
//Server.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include "Listener.h"
#include "SessionManager.h"
using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace clientsession;
SessionManager* _sessionManager;

int main()
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_context iocontext;
        ip::tcp::endpoint ep(ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), PORT_NUMBER); //ipv4, 포트번호
        Listener* _listener = new Listener(iocontext, ep);

        _listener->Start_accept();
        iocontext.run();

    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    while (true)
    {
    }
    return 0;

}
```

I wanna make multithread Server [ one io_context Listener(include accept), multiple io_context Session( for client)]

In other words
I want to change the structure in which session threads are created for each client.
I don't know if the code I created is correct.

N:1 communication is possible, but session processing works synchronously. So I want to make a thread a session and handle it asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

> In other words I want to change the structure in which session threads are created for each client.

This is an anti-pattern in ASIO. You **can**, but read this: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html

One natural way to have separate threads in Asio is to have an `io_context` per thread as well. However, a much *more* natural way would be to have a *strand* ("logical thread") per client and a fixed thread pool that reflects the true number of cores on your system.

> I don't know if the code I created is correct.

Actually you do, because it doesn't compile.

```
    session->_iocontext.post(boost::bind(&Session::StartSession,this)); // error '->*': Cannot convert from'T*' to'Session *'.
```

`this` is `Listener*` here. Of course you cannot bind the method of `Session` to an instance of the `Listener` class. You wanted the session instead:

```
post(session->_iocontext, boost::bind(&Session::StartSession, session));
```

Next up:

- `threadPool.join_all();` appears in `OnAcceptedComplete` meaning that you'll literally await all threads before even considering accepting any other connection. This means that you're in fact better off with a single threaded, blocking server.
- you need to INVOKE `std::this_thread::get_id`: add parentheses `std::this_thread::get_id()` (reminded me of [node addon with cluster get process id returns same id for all forked process's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65265057/node-addon-with-cluster-get-process-id-returns-same-id-for-all-forked-processs/65266803#65266803))
- All your raw pointers and `new` without `delete` is going to lead to a nightmare with memory leaks or stale pointers.

  - why is listener not on the stack?

    ```
      Listener _listener(iocontext, ep);
      _listener.Start_accept();
    ```
  - why would `Socket()` not return a reference? Now you only use it like

    ```
      tcp::socket _socket;
      auto* Socket() { return &_socket; }
      // ...
      _acceptor.async_accept(*(new_session->Socket()),
    ```

    Oof. Simpler:

    ```
      auto& Socket() { return _socket; }
      // ....
      _acceptor.async_accept(new_session->Socket(),
    ```
  - etc.
- You post `StartSession` onto the io service:

  ```
   post(/*some service*/, boost::bind(&Session::StartSession, session));
  ```

  Indeed this makes sense only with a private service for that thread **or** using a strand. With strands it seems redundant still because this always happens on a newly accepted session, so no other thread can possibly know about it.

  > The exception is when you rely on thread local storage?

  > Or maybe your implementation of `GenerateSession` does not result unique sessions?

### Minimal Fixes

Here are my minimal fixes. I suggest NOT using multiple threads (you're doing asynchronous IO anyways).

```
#define PORT_NUMBER 12880
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;

struct Session : std::enable_shared_from_this<Session> {
    template <typename Executor>
    Session(Executor executor) : _socket(make_strand(executor)) {}

    auto& Socket() { return _socket; }

    void StartSession() {
        std::cout << "Session: " << this << " StartSession" << std::endl;
        async_read(_socket, boost::asio::dynamic_buffer(received),
           [self = shared_from_this()](auto ec, size_t tx) { self->on_received(ec, tx); });
    };

  private:
    tcp::socket _socket;
    std::string received;
    void on_received(error_code ec, size_t /*bytes_transferred*/) {
        std::cout << "Session: " << this << " on_received " << ec.message() << " " << std::quoted(received) << std::endl;
    }
};

using SessionPtr = std::shared_ptr<Session>;

namespace clientsession {
    struct SessionManager {
        static SessionManager* GetInstance() {
            static SessionManager instance;
            return &instance;
        }
        template <typename... T> SessionPtr GenerateSession(T&&... args) {
            return std::make_shared<Session>(std::forward<T>(args)...);
        }
    };
} // namespace clientsession

class Listener {
    public:
        Listener(boost::asio::io_context& iosvc, tcp::endpoint ep)
            : _iosvc(iosvc), _acceptor(iosvc, ep) {}

        void Start_accept() {
            // Create Client Session
            auto new_session = clientsession::SessionManager::GetInstance()
                ->GenerateSession(_iosvc.get_executor());

            std::cout << "Listening.....\n\n";
            _acceptor.async_accept(new_session->Socket(),
                    boost::bind(&Listener::OnAcceptComplete, this,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                        new_session));
        }

    private:
        boost::asio::io_context& _iosvc;
        tcp::acceptor _acceptor;
        void OnAcceptComplete(error_code error, SessionPtr session) {
            if (!error) {
                std::cout << "accept completed\n";
                session->StartSession();
                Start_accept();
            } else {
                std::cout << error.message() << '\n';
            }
        }
};

int main() {
    try {
        boost::asio::io_context iocontext;
        Listener listener(iocontext, {{}, PORT_NUMBER}); // ipv4, port number
        listener.Start_accept();

        iocontext.run();
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

When tested with a bunch of simultaneous clients:

```
for a in {1..10};
do
    (sleep 1.$RANDOM; echo -n "hellow world $RANDOM") |
         netcat -w 2 localhost 12880&
done; 
time wait
```

Prints out something like

```
Listening.....

accept completed
Session: 0x56093453c1b0 StartSession
Listening.....

accept completed
Session: 0x56093453de60 StartSession
Listening.....

accept completed
Session: 0x56093453e3c0 StartSession
Listening.....

accept completed
Session: 0x56093453e920 StartSession
Listening.....

accept completed
Session: 0x56093453ee80 StartSession
Listening.....

accept completed
Session: 0x56093453f3e0 StartSession
Listening.....

accept completed
Session: 0x56093453f940 StartSession
Listening.....

accept completed
Session: 0x56093453fea0 StartSession
Listening.....

accept completed
Session: 0x560934540400 StartSession
Listening.....

accept completed
Session: 0x560934540960 StartSession
Listening.....

Session: 0x56093453f940 on_received End of file "hellow world 10149"
Session: 0x56093453fea0 on_received End of file "hellow world 22492"
Session: 0x560934540400 on_received End of file "hellow world 29539"
Session: 0x56093453c1b0 on_received End of file "hellow world 20494"
Session: 0x56093453ee80 on_received End of file "hellow world 24735"
Session: 0x56093453de60 on_received End of file "hellow world 8071"
Session: 0x560934540960 on_received End of file "hellow world 27606"
Session: 0x56093453e920 on_received End of file "hellow world 534"
Session: 0x56093453e3c0 on_received End of file "hellow world 21676"
Session: 0x56093453f3e0 on_received End of file "hellow world 24362"
```

Comment: For some inspiration/alternatives to managing the Session lifetime(s) you can read the links here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65023952/85371

Comment: Improved example to highlight that the sessions are simultaneous

Comment: Your sincere answer has helped me a lot. I also found "this -> Listener -> session" mistake :) I got a lot of inspiration. Thank you